# How to Redirect to another view if Parameter is null in Umbraco

Tags: redirect, url-rewriting, umbraco, umbraco7

I've writter Redirect rule in urlrewriter.config for accepting parameter in url.
Rule is working fine. But, I've scenario when parameter(ID) is null, it should be redirected to work page and if parameter is there below rule should work.

**Ex: www.myDomain.com/case-study/myCasestudy -> Redirect to case-study Page**
**www.myDomain.com/case-study -> Redirect to Work Page**

I can handle this by JQuery in Case study page, But it will redirect first to case study page and after it will redirect to work page

```
<add name="CaseStudyRule" virtualUrl="^~/Case-Study/(.*)" destinationUrl="~/Case-Study.aspx?Id=$1"
rewriteUrlParameter="ExcludeFromClientQueryString"
ignoreCase="true" />
</rewrites>
```

Answer (score 0):

Add two rules: one for virtualUrl="^~/Case-Study" and another for virtualUrl="^~/Case-Study/(.+)"